# How to make Excel table header cover the sheet header?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet where I'm tracking inventory on misc electronics that we keep in stock. I have set up a table that holds all the printers. When I scroll down I know that I can use Freeze Panes to freeze the top row (or any row/column), but I would like the table header to cover the sheet header.

Example:
Headers
[image]

Headers from table covering the headers of the sheet when scrolling down:
[image]

These examples are not from a workbook that I set up so I'm not sure how it's done, but I want to replicate it on workbooks that I have created.

In my file, I have a table that I created beginning in row 1. When I scroll down the table header does not cover the sheet header.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, in Excel 2016, the default behaviour is what you want. If I ***do not*** freeze panes, then any time I scroll down past the table header, the headers overlay the column letters as shown in your second picture. If I scroll down past the bottom of the table, then the headers disappear again.

Table before scrolling down:

[image]

Table after scrolling down 3 rows:

[image]

If I ***do*** freeze panes, the above behaviour does not happen and is not restored when I unfreeze panes (I have to recreate to table to restore the bahaviour).

Comment: Mine does not work this way, I made an update to show this.

Comment: @mike Did you ever freeze panes on that worksheet? I find that if I freeze panes and then unfreeze them, I have to convert the table to a range and then convert back to a table in order to restore the behaviour.

Comment: I don't remember if I have used Freeze panes on this one or not. I did try your trick of converting to a range and then back to a table. Still did not make any change.

Comment: I do have my table starting in row 1 does that make a difference?

Comment: Nevermind, I found that I had Freeze Panes on. I turned it off and did the convert back and forth. It is now working. Thanks!

Comment: I tried deleting the top row so that my table now starts on row 1, and it still works. I am using Excel 2016 as part of Office 365, and it's possible this was added in a recent update (the first time I noticed it was a few weeks ago),

Comment: That could be, I'm using the same as you, just installed last week. I've not seen this behavior in previous versions, but like it and wanted to use it. I saw it in someone else's file (the pictures above) and couldn't figure out how to make it work.